# SelectPdf slow performance on web server

Tags: asp.net, selectpdf

I'm testing the [SelectPdf Community Edition](https://selectpdf.com/community-edition/) for a new project.

I'm converting a single-page HTML document to PDF. On my local dev machine, this takes 2-3 seconds. But when deployed to our test web server, the same conversion takes about 3.5 minutes. (The amount of time is very consistent.)

What could be causing such a slow conversion on the web server and why would it be so different from my development machine?

Comment: It appears the SelectPdf library might be creating an outbound connection while processing. This connection would be blocked by the firewall on our web server, maybe causing SelectPdf to hang while waiting for a response?

Comment: I have also noticed the performance of PDF generation is consistently slow. I assume - they are checking the license against their database. Are you looking at other alternatives?

Comment: I've looked but haven't found a good one yet. Let me know if you have any luck! (For the above project I was able to get away with leaving the page as HTML and adding a good print stylesheet.)

Comment: Just had an aswer from support: "The difference is machine power. The conversion to PDF is very CPU intensive..."

Comment: Thanks, but I'm 100% positive that CPU was not the cause. I'm convinced it was the blocked outbound connection. Using HTML and a well-crafted print stylesheet turned out to be a better solution anyway.